# Check DataGridView for Nulls

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb, rows

I am checking my datagridview in a specific column for a null value, but i cant seem to get it working.

Here is my code :
Thanks.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
      {
          string colTimeOut = DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();    
          MessageBox.Show(colTimeOut);
          if (DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null || 
          DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == string.Empty ||
          DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == "")

          {
              OLEDB_Connection.Open();
              updateCmd.Connection = OLEDB_Connection;
              updateCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestDB (TimeOut) VALUES (@TIMEOUT)";
              updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIMEOUT", varTime);
              updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              OLEDB_Connection.Close();

          }

      else
```

Comment: is there any error or what

Comment: When you write `i < (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)` you can't read the last row by the way..

Comment: should be <= instead or remove -1

Comment: thanks guys. And @tariq there is no error i can see, it just skips to the else statement

Comment: skips even if the value is null or empty ??

Comment: yes. The Message Box i have tells me the value before i check for it, and the message box just shows blank. Which it then shouldnt go to else. Am i correct in saying that ?

Comment: does it work or still not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < (DataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
  {
      string colTimeOut = DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();    
      MessageBox.Show(colTimeOut);
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(colTimeOut))

      {
          OLEDB_Connection.Open();
          updateCmd.Connection = OLEDB_Connection;
          updateCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestDB (TimeOut) VALUES (@TIMEOUT)";
          updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIMEOUT", varTime);
          updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          OLEDB_Connection.Close();

      }

  else
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use like this 
........................

here it is demo example you can modify according to your use ..........

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridInvoice.Rows)   // grdInvoice is data grid view

{

```
                if (row.Cells[SelectColumnIndex].Value != null && Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[SelectColumnIndex].Value) == true)
                {
                    dbObject.AddTaskByInvoice((int)row.Cells[1].Value);

                }
            }
```